# Magento transactional email header

Tags: email, transactional-mail, magento1.9.2.4

When I send a transactional email from Magento 1.9.2.4, some people first see a wrong type of header.
They first see the following and after that the right email.

How can I solve this and/or edit this Notice of License?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org= 
/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> 
<html style=3D"background-color: #fff;"> 
<head> 
<style type=3D"text/css"> 
/** 
* Magento 
* 
* NOTICE OF LICENSE 
* 
* This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0) 
* that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt. 
* It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL: 
* http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php 
* If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to 
* obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email 
* to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately. 
* 
* DISCLAIMER 
* 
* Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer 
* versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your 
* needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information. 
* 
* @category design 
* @package base_default 
* @copyright Copyright (c) 2006-2014 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magent= 
o.com) 
* @license http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php Academic Free L= 
icense (AFL 3.0) 
*/
```

Comment: what is verions of magento?

Comment: @MagentoOdoo.com The version is 1.9.2.4.